# Graph Data Structure - Find minimum number of moves

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

You are standing in a 2D grid at (0,0) . You need to go to (x,y) . In one move you can go from (a,b) to (c,d) if:

1. c and d are integers
2. |a-c|+|b-d|=K (K is provided in the input)

Find if it is possible to reach final destination . If possible what is the minimum number of moves you can take to reach the final destination?

CONSTRAINTS:
-10^5<=x,y<=10^5
1<=K<=10^9

Eg-
INPUT
K=5
X=1, Y=3

OUTPUT
2
[(0,0)->(-3,2)->(1,3)]

In the first move, one can go from (0,0) to (-3,2)
(|0-(-3)| + (0-2) = 3+2 = 5)
and second move,
(-3,2) to (1,3)
(|-3-1| + |2-3| = 4+1 = 5)

Hence 2.

Comment: `|a-b|+|b-d|=K` I suspect this is a typo and you meant `|a-c|+|b-d|=K`?

Comment: Corrected it. Thanks! :)

Comment: This is the [Manhattan Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) metric.  IIRC, if K is odd, then you can reach any square, otherwise, it has Bishop-like limitations (from Chess) on which squares it can reach.

Comment: I am fairly new to graphs, can you please help me solve the question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I believe you're mistaken, and that for any even k we can reach half the squares. E.g., k=2^n, (0, 0) -> (2^n, 0) -> (1,1). Similarly, all adjacent diagonals can be reached.

Comment: @Dave Hmm, you are correct.  Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

The comments asserted a necessary criterion, that `2` must divide `|x| + |y|` at least as many times as it divides `k`.  You should prove it.

But now suppose that `P` is a path from `(0, 0)` to `(x, y)`.  Let's let `P_h` be the sum of the lengths of the horizontal steps you take.  Similarly let `P_v` be the sum of the lengths of the vertical steps you take.  The following are easy to show:

1. `|x| ≤ P_h`
2. `2` divides `P_h - |x|`
3. `|y| ≤ P_v`
4. `2` divides `P_v - |y|`
5. `k` divides `P_h + P_v` and in fact the number of steps taken is `(P_h + P_v)/k`.

Between these facts, if `i*k` is the first multiple of `k` which is at least `|x| + |y|` with `i*k - |x| - |y|` even, then any path of length `i*k` must be minimal.

To finish, show that you can always construct a path of that length.  And then the problem becomes easy.

Comment: "The comments asserted a necessary criterion, that 2 must divide |x| + |y| at least as many times as it divides k. You should prove it." k=4, x=y=1, (0,0) -> (-2,2) -> (1,1)

Comment: When you talk about a path of length i*k, do you mean i moves of length k each? I think your approach applied to k=5, x=0, y=1 would suggest 1 move of length 5, but the minimum is 3 moves of length 5.

Comment: @Dave You are correct about the necessary criterion having been wrong. When I talk about a path of length `i*k` I do mean `i` moves of length `k` each. And shoot, but you are right.  You want a path of length `i*k` such that the point where you turn around is at the end of a step.  If the path has at least 2 steps, that's easy, but you can't do that for a single step path. :-(

Comment: My solution was to special case distances within k of the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Constant time solution.

All distances here are Manhattan distances.

Everything a distance of k from the origin can be reached in one step. This forms a diamond shape.

Within that diamond, every tile an even distance from the origin can be reached in 2 steps.

If k is odd, then every tile in the diamond an odd distance from the origin can be reached in 3 steps. If k is even then these tiles can't be reached.

Let's call (x, y) the target. The target can be reached unless k is even and |x| + |y| is odd.

If the target is inside the diamond, determine whether it can be reached in 0, 1, 2, or 3 based on the rules above.

If the target is outside the diamond, find the distance between the target and the closest corner (closest of (-k,0), (k,0), (0,-k), (0,k)). Call this d.

If d%k == 0 then it takes d/k moves to get to the corner, +1 to get to the center. Otherwise, after reaching the corner, we have a remaining distance of d%k to move. If this is even we can stay along the edge of the diamond where we have one additional move to get to the origin. If this is odd then k must also be odd and we can be adjacent to the edge of the diamond where there are two moves to the origin.

Here's some Ruby code that implements this.

```
def get_moves(x, y, k)
  distance = get_dist(0, 0, x, y)

  # return 0 to 3 for reachable distances inside the diamond
  # return -1 for unreachable distances
  return -1 if k % 2 == 0 && distance % 2 == 1
  return 0 if distance == 0
  return 1 if distance == k
  return 2 if distance < k && distance % 2 == 0
  return 3 if distance < k && distance % 2 == 1
  
  # Find the distance between the target & nearest corner of the diamond
  distance_to_corner = [get_dist(x, y, 0, -k), get_dist(x, y, 0, k), get_dist(x, y, -k, 0), get_dist(x, y, k, 0)].min

  # Find the extra distance since we're going in steps of size k
  extra_distance = (k - distance_to_corner % k) % k
  
  # If the extra distance is even then we can stay along the
  # edge of the diamond which is 1 move from the origin.
  # Otherwise we're adjacent to the edge of the diamond,
  # putting us 2 moves from the origin.
  if extra_distance % 2 == 0
    return 1 + (distance_to_corner + extra_distance) / k
  else
    return 2 + (distance_to_corner + extra_distance) / k
  end
end

def get_dist(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)
  return (x_2 - x_1).abs + (y_2 - y_1).abs
end
```